# using php to add classes to li then alternate after every third item?

Tags: php, css, addclass

this may be stupidly simple but I'm trying to figure out a way to add a class to an unordered list, then alternate that class after every third item..

I've only mananged to add a class on every third item (which is not what I want), but here's my code:

```
<?php $i=1; foreach($this->items as $item) : ?>
      <li class="<?php if ($i % 3 == 0) : ?>odd<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $linky; ?>">xxx</a></li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Which spits out:

```
<li class="">xxx</li>
<li class="">xxx</li>
<li class="odd">xxx</li>
<li class="">xxx</li>
<li class="">xxx</li>
<li class="odd">xxx</li>
```

But what I'm hoping to get is:

```
<li class="odd">xxx</li>
<li class="odd">xxx</li>
<li class="odd">xxx</li>
<li class="even">xxx</li>
<li class="even">xxx</li>
<li class="even">xxx</li>
```

and so forth.. Normally I'd use jquery to do something like this, but I have to use php in this case.. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you confirm the "What I'm hoping to get is" markup? That seems very unusual as the class names are no-longer descriptive of the content (i.e. odd items don't have the "odd" class).

Comment: Sorry, it made sense to me. I was using three li's per "row" so to speak. So each set of three li's would be laid out differently :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a boolean flag which is flipped (negated) every time `$i % 3 == 0`:

```
// Start with 0 instead of 1
$i=0;
// Flag starts TRUE
$state = TRUE;
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
  if ($i % 3 === 0) {
    // Flip to opposite state
    $state = !$state;
  }
  ?>
  <li class="<?php if ($state) : ?>odd<?php else: ?>even<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $linky; ?>">xxx</a></li> 
  <?php
  $i++;
}
```

[Here is a demonstration](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HvxDm3). Though you'll need to inspect the output to see the classes change.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator.

```
if ($i % 3 == 0)
```

means "If the remainder of $i divided by 3 is 0".

What you want is

```
if (floor($i/3) == 0).
```

Give it a try and see how it goes.

EDIT: You also seem to be missing the 'else' code. If you don't have that, it won't write 'even' for the non-'odd' classes.

EDIT EDIT: If you want the pattern to continue, use:

```
if ((floor($i/3) % 2) == 0).
```

Comment: Palladium - `(floor($i/3) == 0)` evaluates to true for i between 0 and 2, otherwise it's false - not what the author was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Yah I know I was missing the else tag, I was just trying to get 3 to say odd first lol

Comment: @SamDufel But that's exactly what the author's "what I'm hoping to get" says. Even if the class name is 'odd' or 'even', her intended result isn't alternating 'odd' and 'even'.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the 7th item to be "odd"? I wrote JavaScript, but should easily convert to PHP

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNx39/)

```
for (var i = 0; ​i < 15; i++) {
    if(i%6 < 3) {
document.write("odd<br>");
    }
    else {
document.write("even<br>")     
    }        
}​
```

Changing your code to:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->items as $item) : ?>
      <li class="<?php if ($i % 6 < 3) : ?>odd<?php else: ?>even<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $linky; ?>">xxx</a></li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the new CSS3 selectors that allow you to target odd and even childs.

Here is a link with an example.  Basically, you'd have your list just as normal.

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Then rather than having a class called odd and even with the different styles, you can use the new selectors like this...

```
li:nth-child(even) { background: #fff; }
li:nth-child(odd) { background:#000; }
```

This will make all even list items have a background of #fff and all odd list items with a background of #000.

**Edit: You can use a couple other CSS3 selectors to only target the even and odds after the first two using 1st-child and 2nd-child.**

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting a for each loop within a for loop. With the outer loop telling how many times to iterate and the inner loops telling how many times to put odd and even.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only printing every three iterations of your loop is that you are using the modulus operator `"%"` to test if i is divisible by three `($i % 3 == 0)`.  This results in only printing when $i is divisible by 3.

To solve your problem:

```
<?php
$odd = "<li class='odd'>";
$even = "<li class='even'>";
$i = 0;

foreach($this->items as $item)
{
  if($i < 3)
    echo $odd . $item . "</li>";
  else if($i >= 3)
    echo $even . $item . "</li>";
  $i++;
  if($i > 5)
    $i = 0;
}
?>
```

Note that since $i begins at 0, the first 3 items will be indexed 0 - 2, and the subsequent 3 will be indexed 3 - 5.